# Is elementary OS Lenovo B41-30 compatible or not?

Tags: system-installation, lenovo

I'm new to Linux and I want to try the elementary OS as a replacement for my current OS but I'm not sure if my laptop meets the minimum requirements for elementary OS to run properly. Would be awesome if you guys tell me if my laptop meets the minimum requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what [elementary OS' website](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#recommended-system-specifications) says,

> **Recommended System Specifications**
>
> While we don't have a strict set of minimum system requirements, we recommend at least the following specifications for the best experience:
>
> - Recent Intel i3 or comparable dual-core 64-bit processor
> - 4 GB of system memory (RAM)
> - Solid state drive (SSD) with 15 GB of free space
> - Internet access
> - 1024×768 display

However, the machine I run elementary OS as primary OS doesn't have SSD but I don't see any problem. It is running smoothly.

Now, check your system information if you don't know yet, if your system meet this requirements you can install elementary OS.

Answer (score 0):

I use Lenovo ideapad 110 running normal no lag..